# Android iconGravity not working for MaterialButton with CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, progress-indicator, android-gravity

I've created a custom view that extends MaterialButton that replaces the drawable with a CircularProgressIndicator when it's loading.

However when I replace the drawable with the CircularProgressIndicator the iconGravity doesn't work anymore. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I've been able to boil the class down to this:

```
class LoadingButton constructor(context: Context) : MaterialButton(context) {

    private val progressIndicatorDrawable by lazy {
        val progressIndicatorSpec = CircularProgressIndicatorSpec(context, null, 0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_CircularProgressIndicator_ExtraSmall)
        progressIndicatorSpec.indicatorColors = intArrayOf(getColor(context, R.color.white))
        IndeterminateDrawable.createCircularDrawable(context, progressIndicatorSpec).apply {
            setVisible(true, true)
        }
    }

    init {
        // the following drawable is aligned to the start of the view (incorrect).
        icon = progressIndicatorDrawable
        // the following drawable is aligned to the start of the text (correct).
        // icon = DrawableUtil.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_delete)
        text = "Delete"
        iconGravity = ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START
    }
}
```

I'm using this dependency

```
// I've also tried 1.5.0-alpha02
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
```

**Correct position** The drawable is positioned at the start of the text.
[image: drawable correct position]

**Incorrect position** The progress indicator is not positioned at the start of the text anymore.
[image: progress indicator incorrect position]

Comment: It seems a bug. Can you use compose as workaround?

Comment: I would have to look into that. I don't have any experience with compose yet.

Comment: Like others suggested this seems like a bug in de material components library, so I've reported an issue: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is curious that one drawable works but another doesn't. It may be worth reporting as a bug. In the meantime, I can offer a workaround that doesn't involve a lot of work (IMO).

If we take your custom view and remove the `iconGravity` and set the gravity for the text to the start and vertical center:

```
gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
```

we can get the indeterminate and the text together on the left side of the button:

[image]

The issue now is how to get the pair centered in the button. We can take a hint from the [code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/f3e03107df935851758db8a24ac74f8ad21dfaeb/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java#L499) for *MaterialButton* on an approach on how much space is needed on the left to center the drawable and text.

```
int newIconLeft =
    (buttonWidth
        - getTextWidth()
        - ViewCompat.getPaddingEnd(this)
        - localIconSize
        - iconPadding
        - ViewCompat.getPaddingStart(this))
        / 2;
```

Putting it all together:

[image]

Here is the demo code. It may require some tweaking if your actual button is more complex than is pictured in your question.

```
class LoadingButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs) {

    // true - use indeterminate; false = use delete icon
    private val useIndeterminate = true

    private val progressIndicatorDrawable by lazy {
        val progressIndicatorSpec = CircularProgressIndicatorSpec(
            context,
            null,
            0,
            R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_CircularProgressIndicator_ExtraSmall
        )
        progressIndicatorSpec.indicatorColors = intArrayOf(getColor(context, R.color.white))
        IndeterminateDrawable.createCircularDrawable(context, progressIndicatorSpec).apply {
            setVisible(true, true)
        }
    }

    init {
        if (useIndeterminate) {
            icon = progressIndicatorDrawable
            gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
        } else {
            icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_delete)
            iconGravity = ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
        text = "Delete"
    }

    // This is homw much we need to shift the contents of the button to the right in order to
    // center it.
    private var xShift = 0f
    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        if (useIndeterminate) {
            xShift = (width
                    - icon.intrinsicWidth
                    - paint.measureText(text.toString())
                    - iconPadding
                    - ViewCompat.getPaddingStart(this)
                    - ViewCompat.getPaddingEnd(this)) / 2f
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        // Shift right before drawing.
        canvas?.withTranslation(xShift) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an acceptable work-around for this bug. I needed to tweak the code a bit and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: it seems a bug of the material components library and this answer is not the solution for the code reported in the answer.

If you can use Compose as workaround just apply something like:

```
Button (
    modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp),
    onClick = { /* Do something! */ }
){
    CircularProgressIndicator(color = White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(24.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically))
    Spacer(Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
    Text("Delete")
}
```

[image]

To incorporate the Compose UI content in an existing layout, just add in the xml layout:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and in your Fragment or Activity:

```
    val view: ComposeView = findViewById(R.id.compose_view)
    view.apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                /* The code above */
                Button (
                    onClick = { /* Do something! */ }){
                    CircularProgressIndicator(color = White, modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp).align(
                        Alignment.CenterVertically))
                    Spacer(Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
                    Text("Delete")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you can find more details about the [Interoperability](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments).

Comment: There is another answer that doesn't require me to migrate this code to compose. 
However this will come in handy once we start migrating to compose. Thanks for your effort.